# What causes refraction of visible light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction

[Refraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction) is the bending of a wave when it enters a medium where its speed is different. The refraction of light when it passes from a fast medium to a slow medium bends the light ray toward the normal to the boundary between the two media.
My question is what is the fundamental reason for this refraction?is it something related to the atomic force?

Comment: What is "atomic force" for you?

Comment: Forces between two atoms,bonding forces.i think its same for all.

Comment: The refraction is caused by a change in the speed of light, and this is due to interactions with electrons in the solid. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44751/ for more on this. Also my answer to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56188/. And also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65156/. And finally http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81799/. None of these is an exact duplicate though.

Comment: Simply put,"Boundary conditions for dielectrics".

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the mechanism behind the slowdown of light/photons in a transparent medium?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/466/what-is-the-mechanism-behind-the-slowdown-of-light-photons-in-a-transparent-medi). See also: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11820/what-really-cause-light-photons-to-appear-slower-in-media and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2041/how-are-classical-optics-phenomena-explained-in-qed-snells-law

Answer (score 2):

Refraction of light can be derived using classical electrodynamics. When light passes from one medium to another, its speed changes according to propagation constant. The frequency of light cannot change, so to make up for the changed speed, the wavelength changes. If you apply the boundary conditions, you get snell's law of refraction - refer to a classical electrodynamics book. See also [Snell's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell's_law).