# Why does special relativity talk about the speed of light in a vacuum?

Tags: special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light

What's the importance of the speed of light being in a vacuum?  Does not being in a vacuum cause a difference?

Comment: _Does not being in a vacuum cause a difference?_ Yes, it's no longer the maximum speed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speed of light in a vacuum](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44751/)

Answer (score 1):

The speed of light is based on what medium the light is travelling in. The speed of light in a vacuum is the fastest speed at which light would travel, and is a constant. (The changing speed of light in different mediums is also where the phenomena of diffraction and refraction come from.)

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the first part of this page:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Special_Relativity/Spacetime#The_modern_approach_to_special_relativity

The geometric approach to special relativity, instead of directly assuming the constancy of the speed of light in a vacuum, assumes that the space-time interval between two events is independent of how fast an inertial observer is traveling. This is analogous to how the length of a three-dimensional vector is independent of the coordinate axes used to describe it.

A consequence of this assumption is that there should be **one (and only one)** particular speed $c$ that is a universal constant. If something is moving at speed $c$, then all inertial observers, regardless of how fast they are themselves moving, will measure its speed to be $c$.

In careful experiments that have been performed over the years, it has been found that the speed of light in a vacuum seems to be constant in exactly this manner. Therefore, it is equated with the universal constant $c$.

On the other hand, the speed of propagation of light in materials such as glass or even air is measurably lower than the value in a vacuum. Since no speeds besides $c$ are universal constants in the theory of relativity, these lower values have no special place in the theory.

Answer (score 0):

The direction of electromagnetic wave gets affected in a medium other than vacuum. So the EM wave has to travel longer distances and hence a change in velocity. The actual velocity of light remains constant but ,light maybe absorbed and re emitted, or ,deviated by electric fields produced by dipoles, or deviated by magnetic fields. All this may not be used in field equations. The primary parameter is the magnetic permeability(μ) and electric permittivity(ε). 
Light speed(c)=1/(ε*μ) .

Answer (score 0):

> Why does special relativity talk about the speed of light in a vacuum?

When there's a medium, we must consider

(1) the speed with which light propagates relative to the material medium

(2) the speed of the medium relative to the frame of reference

(3) the speed of light relative to the frame of reference

However, when there isn't a material medium, when light propagates *in vacuo*, there is *only* (3), the speed of light relative to a frame of reference to consider.

A postulate of Special Relativity is that the measured speed of light *in vacuo* is *c* in *all* inertial reference frames.

It follows that *c* is a limiting and universal speed, i.e., an object with speed less than *c* in one frame of reference has speed less than *c* in *all* frames of reference; an object with speed *c* in one frame has speed *c* in *all* frames.

Thus, *c* is of special importance in that it is a universal constant and an invariant speed, the speed of light *in vacuo*.